# What to check if Centos server is very slow

Tags: linux, centos

I have Linux VPS server 2Gb RAM but when i usee ssh then it is very slow. Sometimes it takes many seconds to see the character typed.

I tried `free -m` and it says 1670MB free

I tried top command and there is no command having high cpu usage. only sshd is using 0.3% CPU.

Comment: What is the speed of your connection? Your problem may be related to low bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

I think your internet line is slow rather than your vps from your remarks.

When you connect with ssh on  a slow line (or when you are downloading) you can make the shell lag.

Answer (score 1):

Your VPS provider is either capping upload (at least) or is being DDOS'd or flooded to death. I have found that most "cheap" VPS providers have these issues.

Comment: My idea exactly, but I did not want to state it so crude :)

Comment: My bad if offensive, sorry.

Comment: How can i check that if that is the case

Comment: Try a large SSH transfer to your VPS, that you give you an idea how the connection is.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said it's very possible it's your home internet.

I have the same problem due to packet loss, at peak times I get between 10-40% packet loss, this makes characters take as long as 5 seconds to appear on my terminal, very frustrating.

Do a ping test at http://pingtest.net/ to check.